# Local Storage , jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have 2 html files , let's say : a.html and b.html . 
In the a.html I have a jquery event like when the users clicks a text it will change some CSS settings . What I want is to pass those new CSS settings to the b.html . I've heard that I should use cookies or localStorage . Can somebody get me an example of syntax I should be using?
Thanks

Comment: if you want the settings for a session only then better use sessionStorage

Comment: That's the problem @Banana. I want to store some CSS settings that are applied after a jqeury function and then pass to the next html file . I am new to web development so I have no idea how to do this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: @LKB then i would strongly suggest going over the tutorials [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/). if you encounter any problem while programming, we will be happy yo assist you

Comment: https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/localstorage-and-sessionstorage

Comment: @Banana . I've been learning from W3Shool . I know html , css , some javascript and primarily using jquery for effects (basic jquery) . So yea. Got a lot to learn :D

Comment: You can use "URL rewriting". Google it. Navigate to b.html as "b.html?style1=val1&style2=val2" ans so on ...